# how to change the layout folder using express-handlebar

Tags: express, handlebars.js

When using `app.engine` and `express-handlebars` to use change the folder directory I encountered an error:

```
var hbs= require("express-handlebars");
app.engine("hbs", hbs({
   extname: "hbs",
   defaultLayout: "layout",
   layoutsDir: path.join(__dirname, "views", "layout"), 
   // Corrected path partialsDir: path.join(__dirname, "views", "parts"),
  })
);
```

This is my [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAEp1.png)

Comment: Did you follow the documentation? https://github.com/express-handlebars/express-handlebars#using-instances

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear. `hbs` is not a function. You need to use `hbs.engine()`.

```
app.engine("hbs", hbs.engine({
   extname: "hbs",
   defaultLayout: "layout",
   layoutsDir: path.join(__dirname, "views", "layout") //< Your new layoutsDir can go here
}));
```

However, you are using Node v18.17 so I would suggest you follow the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-handlebars) and use [ES Modules](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html) `import` statement. You will find it easier to leverage this package.